# Why is index.ejs throwing a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ejs

I'm rendering my React app on the server, but I am getting an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`, when I check the where the error occurs this line is pointed out. [image: index.ejs] I have already installed ejs version 2.5.6. Below is my node server code. What am I doing wrong? My index.ejs code is located in the views folder. Let me know if you need any additional code like my `app.get('*')` function.

index.js (node server)

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

index.ejs (inside views folder)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css"></link>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/style/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"><%- markup -%></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: EJS hasn't been updated since almost 3 years now, are you sure you don't want to use a more recent library? If you're using React, common practice is to not use a view engine at all but rather use renderToString to turn your React components to an HTML string and serve that to the user with res.send(). You can add the basic HTML structure around your React layout through simple string concatenation.

Comment: @joethemow Can you please post answer if you got the solution. I'm getting exactly same issue.